# Explanation about the ConfigurationServers on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and after reading a big part of the documentation on the MongoDB website, I'm searching some explanations about the ConfigServers on a sharded MongoDB cluster.

First, just to be sure, can we instantiate more than 3 ConfigServers?
And then what happens when we add a ConfigServer dynamically?

The goal of this question is to know if it is possible to group the ConfigServers and the routers on a same node. The inconvenient is that when we add a router, we add a ConfigServer.

Thank you in advance for the explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And then what happens when we add a ConfigServer dynamically?

Nothing, MongoDB is hardcoded to a max of 3 (currently).

> The goal of this question is to know if it is possible to group the ConfigServers and the routers on a same node

You can since the resource usage of all these parts should be low enough but you will risk the redundancy of the network making it easier to lose a part or all of your cluster.

> The inconvenient is that when we add a router, we add a ConfigServer.

Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't notice that the number of 3 ConfigServers was hardcoded.